# Filter Table by Search Fields (Excel)

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a table in excel, and I want my users to be able to filter on it based on a few search fields.

I want them to be able to search part of the field (i.e. McD) and I want them to be able to fill in 1, 2 or 3 of the criteria.

I found the code below online but it is limited and doesn't seem to work

```
   If Target.Address = Range("E2").Address Then
       Range("A1:C20").CurrentRegion.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:=Range("E1:E2")
   End If
End Sub
```

Please see the image below for illustration

[image]

Comment: Please update your picture in a way to show Rows and Column. Otherwise, nobody can understand where the table to be filtered exists...

Comment: Try the code I posted, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test the next code, please. But before that, please arrange your filter criteria transposed.

I mean to have your fields name on first row (from A1 to C1), and criteria (McDonalds, for instance) on second row (from A2 to C2):

```
Sub testFilterAutomation()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, lastRow As Long
  Set sh = ActiveSheet ' use here your sheet
  lastRow = sh.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    sh.Range("A5:G" & lastRow).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:=sh.Range("A1:C2")
End Sub
```

If you want to automate the process, copy, please the next code in the sheet module:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.address(0, 0) = "E1" Then
        If UCase(Target.Value) = "X" Or UCase(Target.Value) = "Y" Then
            Dim lastRow As Long
            lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
              Range("A5:G" & lastRow).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:=Range("A1:C2")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

If you change the E1 value in "X" or "Y" the code will be triggered. You can use a Data Validation list (with only x and y) and changing from one to the other, the code will be triggered.

Comment: WOW it works perfectly!!!! Thank you FaneDuru!!!! I've accepted answer :)

Comment: FaneDuru, when I use the filter, it only works if I type exactly what is in the search field. For example, I have to type McDonalds in Vendor name. If I type McD, the filter doesn't work.

Comment: @Hashmat Habibzadah: Do you have 'McD' vendor name in the range to be filtered?

Comment: No, but if I type in McD, I want all McDonalds to show up

Comment: @Hashmat Habibzadah: Very interesting. I want winning the lottery, too... But I cannot control that... Based on what would you like Excel  to make this change? Theoretically, you can create an equivalence list between your real vendor names and alias you want to apply and design a piece of code to make the change. But this is something different and I can not understand how can you imagine that this change could be done by itself, only because you want it, no offence...

Comment: Ok this is weird. Basically, the more I type, the better it works. If have a list of addresses, and if I search "31" I get nothing. but if i type "31 Bruce" then it returns the right store

Comment: Of course! It returns **based on strictly what you have in that range**! The filtering does not work in the way you intuited. You may try `31*` . Using the Wildcard Character... But Excel itself cannot guess what is your need.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215836/discussion-between-hashmat-habibzadah-and-faneduru).